# Oracle 11g Backup and Recovery

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

**I have installed Oracle in E Drive.**
**I need to format my OS located in C Drive.**
Now I need to backup whole database so that when installed new OS, oracle database works fine.

Comment: Better on dba.stackexchange.com but a prime question is what is the new OS you are going to install ? The volume of data is also useful (and whether you intend changing the version of the database at the same time)

Comment: i mean i want to reinstall the OS(the same Windows XP) and want to recover the oracle database with the same version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to re-install the Oracle database software.
The data that forms the database can be backed up/restored using RMAN or manually. I recommend you practice a restore before blowing away your current environment.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/osbackup.htm#autoId3

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/osrecvry.htm#autoId18